# How to make a property only readable in a swift package while can be accessed outer of it?

Tags: swift, swift-package

I'm making a swift package using existing code to separate a class as a module from the main project.

My original code makes properties `private(set)`, which is intended to make it only readable (not settable).

```
// Original code
// A property of the class
@Published private(set) var index: Int = 0
```

But Xcode reports an error `'index' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level`. I assume I have to change the `private(set)` into `public`. But I also want to protect it from editing outside of the class, which means still using `private(set)`. Is there any syntax to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every property has a combination of accessibilities for `get` and `set`.

The default is

```swift
internal internal(set)
```

You seem to want

```swift
public private(set)
```